# Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus SendMessageAsync timing out every 2 min?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We are currently using v3 azure functions in a k8s cluster to send multiple messages to different queues in a service bus.

Here's the code we're using:

```
await using ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(_configuration["AzureWebJobsServiceBus"]);

ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);
ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(response);

await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
```

For some reason we can observe a pattern where every ~2 min our .SendMessageAsync() seems to freeze and eventually timeout after 2 mins.

[image: message graph]

If we increase the amount of functions running in parallel, we would observe a higher peak, but the timeouts would occur at the same intervals.

The failed method from AppInsight:

Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope+d__57.MoveNext

We believe that when we call .SendMessageAsync, a connection to the queue is attempted, but eventually times out. We are aware of [Azure Service Bus quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas) and are currently running on the standard tier. When we look at the metrics of our service bus, nothing seems to be in the red.

After a thorough research online, we can't seem to find any information anywhere (or anyone else) that has the same problem as we do.

Packages being used:

- Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.1.2
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.11

Any chance we can get pointed towards a solution or a cause to our problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can try is sharing the ServiceBusClient between Azure Function instances:

```
private static ServiceBusClient _client = new ServiceBusClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsServiceBus"));

[FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    ServiceBusSender sender = _client.CreateSender(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("QueueName");
    ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(response);

    await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
    
    return new OkObjectResult();
}
```

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/

https://youtu.be/XO7TjQOQB_A?t=2450

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running into the 5000 connection limit mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas#messaging-quotas). Each ServiceBusClient instance uses its own AMQP connection.